# Error while entering data into a table with Primary Key formed by multiple columns, each referenced from other tables

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, multiple-columns

I have 4 tables, 3 of which have their own primary keys. In the 4th table, the primary keys of all the other 3 tables are referenced as foreign keys and these are made into a primary key (combination of all 3 foreign keys). However, upon entering data into the columns, I get constraint violation errors. 
The code snippets are as below:

```
    --Table # 1
    create table PartSupplier(
        partSupplierID int primary key,
        fName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        lName varchar(20),
        houseNO varchar(20),
        streetName varchar(20),
        city varchar(20),
        dob date,
        contactNo varchar(50)
   )
   --Table # 2
   create table PartSpecialist(
            partSpecialistID int primary key,
        fName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        lName varchar(20),
        houseNO varchar(20),
        streetName varchar(20),
        city varchar(20),
        dob date,
        contactNo varchar(15)
   )
   --Table # 3
   create table CarPart(
        partNumber int primary key,
        description varchar (250),
        vehicleID int NOT NULL,
        imagePath varchar(50)
   )
   --Table # 4 (with multiple foreign keys made into one primary key)
   create table SpecialistSuppliedPart(
        partSpecialistID int NOT NULL,
        partSupplierID int NOT NULL,
        partNumber int NOT NULL,
        condition varchar(10),
        dateAcquired date,
        costPrice int NOT NULL,
        constraint specialist_supplier_part_PK primary key (partSpecialistID, partSupplierID, partNumber),
        foreign key (partSpecialistID) references PartSpecialist(partSpecialistID),
        foreign key (partSupplierID) references PartSupplier(partSupplierID),
        foreign key (partNumber) references CarPart(partNumber)
   )
```

I tried inserting the following values in the table:

```
    3   3   5   USED    5000    2011-03-01
    3   13  18  NEW 6000    2011-06-26
```

upon which I got the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhFk2.jpg

where FK_SpecialistSuppliedPart_PartSupplier is the Foreign Key existing between Table # 1 and Table # 4.

I have all of these entries existing in the respective tables. After an exhaustive search on the internet (including stackoverflow.com), I could not find a solution.
What am I doing wrong here?
P.S. I tried adding the Foreign and Primary keys using MSSQLs Design Tool but it still results in the same error.

Comment: What's your full insert statement? Your column order isn't as described in the table so which number is which? Also you have checked that those ID's actually exist in the parent tables first, right? I say that because your error message suggests that whatever you're trying to insert into PartSupplierId in table 4 does not exist in table 1.

Comment: Also, if you're importing from Excel are you sure that the tables are being populated in the correct order? Are you improting everything at once? I so, tables 1 through 3 **must** be populated before you can import from table 4 unless you disable the constraints first and then re-enable `WITH CHECK` after to ensure integrity (althoguh if there is a mis-match you'll still get an error when you try to enable the constraints again).

Comment: @StevePettifer
I was initially trying to import data from an Excel file that I have. Here is an image of what happens when I try to use the Import Tool:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c91h7nbyrxqz4xi/sql_error_2.JPG
This is the state of the Table#4 (error after using Design View to insert data):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m07swjan3ggucj4/sql_error_3.JPG
States of other tables:
Table#1:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q46myx1nmaxfwtd/part_supp.JPG
Table#2:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y30nogwa98a85q5/sql_error_spec.JPG
Table#3:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g74azwb8gut880/sql_error_part.JPG

Comment: I have figured out my mistake: The entry 13 does not exist in the 1st table. This was a pretty foolish mistake to make. 
@StevePettifer Thanks for the response.

Comment: No worries. We all do it sometimes.